# How to render text on rectangle box in opengl-es

Tags: opengl-es, gpu, mali-400

I wrote a simple OpenGLES app using Mali-400 GPU. I am grabbing buffers from camera and rendering using GPU. On top of the camera stream, I want to render few rectangle boxes with some configurable text.
What is the best approach to render text on the rectangle in OpenGLES ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to render text into OpenGL surface there are many ways to do this:

1. You can render whole text into image, load it into texture and draw it. This approach can be slow and memory expensive.
2. You can render separate chars of text. Build atlas from it. Load it into texture and render text from separate chars. With this approach it is hard to properly render text in languages like Arabic, Thai, etc
3. Use harfbuzz + FreeType to render text in any language. This is hard but will produce best result.

If you need to show text over OpenGL surface - you can use regular TextView.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to render text using cairo library using cairo_image_surface_create_for_data function. This function takes a pointer to my frame and creates cairo surface. I then create a cairo state on which I write text using cairo_show_text. This approach uses CPU.  In second approach I tried to use cairo-gl. I created a cairo surface from EGL surface using cairo_gl_surface_create_for_egl function . but the problem with this approach is ,I am able to see the text box only. the background scene rendered by opengl is not appearing. is there any solution to this ?